# Почему не показывается изображение в ie

Tags: css

Во всех браузерах работает, кроме ie

```
.front_mid_news:after {
    width: 61px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    left: -61px;
    top: 0;
    background: url(../img/front_mid_news_after.png);
}
```

Comment: попробуй url в кавычки

Comment: @Grundy не работает

Comment: покажи что и как обернул :)

Comment: @Grundy нужно display: block добавить:)

Comment: не исключено :) зависит от значения по умолчанию для псевдо элементов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте следующее к `:after`.

`display: block;`

Это должно решить вашу проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Измените в `height` `%` на `px`:

```
.front_mid_news:after {
    width: 61px;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    left: -61px;
    top: 0;
    background: url(../img/front_mid_news_after.png);
}
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/521276)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, почему не является?

Comment: @Grundy Слишком коротко. Надо бы немного кода добавить для примера.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, для примера замены % на px?

Comment: @Grundy Ну да, взять код из вопроса, поменять что надо, добавить в ответ, и (желательно/опционально) объяснить почему так будет работать. Ну это мое понимание типичного ответа здесь ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, если рассматривать под таким углом твои ответы - то они тоже не являются ответами, так как просто куски кода, непонятно как связанные с вопросом, без каких либо пояснений почему так будет работать. Ты их удалишь сейчас? :) Как минимум последние 5 ответов. Могу пройти по всем - и так же почистить "не ответы"

Comment: @Grundy _и (желательно/опционально) объяснить почему так будет работать_ ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, так твои ответы точно такие же как и этот :) а раз нет разницы ;-)

Comment: Большинство моих ответов, @Grundy — просто код.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, именно, и это фактически не ответ, мало ли что там за код, например удаляет все с диска :)

Comment: @Grundy https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1181498/revisions

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, а ты уверен, что именно это имел ввиду автор? Выглядит как изменение смысла ответа

Comment: @Grundy Других `%` там нет.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, 100% не равно 100px

Comment: @Grundy Имелось ввиду перевести что ли?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, спрашивать, что имелось ввиду лучше до правки, а не после :)

Comment: @Grundy "Последнее посещение вчера"

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, и?

Comment: @Grundy У кого спросить?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, из-за того, что псевдоэлементы изначально задавались через `::` after просто не работает. Попробуйте поменять `:after` на `::after`.